Is that possible in SharePoint?
I'm wondering in SharePoint online, is it possible for any list (mosaic, regular list, etc.) that have some elements, to display them only to user that are in specific security groups Microsoft 365. And if yes, how would you do such a thing?
My goal is to do a portal site for a company and display certain element only to visitor that are on certain security groups (extraction of active directory). I've tried to do custom list etc. but don't manage to even touch this goal.
And something I don't understand, I have to find the place where you add authorizations for the site but I can't add security groups because it adds the email related to that security group and not the member of the group itself. And I can't find a way to use security groups for site authorizations and the thing I mentioned a little bit earlier to display element of list.
Thank you in advance for all you're answers.

I think there are two concepts in SharePoint than can help you:

Audience targeting: by enabling audience targeting, specific content will be prioritized to specific audiences through SharePoint web parts, page libraries, and navigational links.

Item level permissions: it's a feature that allows users or groups to view specific items within a list.


How to Enable Item Level Permissions in SharePoint (Guide)
How to enable Item Level Permissions in SharePoint
Item level permission based on groups rather than user
Enable item level permissions in SharePoint | quick & efficient methods revealed!

I don't think this solution can work in my case because i want to show items regardless of who creates it. I want to grant acces to items i create to security groups. And when i try to add group it does'nt add group but only add the email related to the group.

SharePoint permissions are managed by SharePoint groups (built-in groups like Owners, Members and Visitors, but also custom groups). Within these groups, you can add users or groups (Microsoft 365 groups, Entra groups). So you can restrict item visibility to SharePoint groups that reference security groups.
